# Como padronizar tamanho vertical do box com CSS?

Tags: css

Tenho o seguinte CSS:

```
.course-content {
    padding-top: 22px;
    padding-bottom: 30px;
}
```

Dentro do loop em PHP, busco os registros do banco de dados.
Fica dessa maneira:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Com isso, notei que ficou com tamanhos diferentes. De que forma eu posso padronizar a altura? Não gostaria de definir uma altura fixa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Não sei se vai te servir exatamente, mas exite uma solução apenas em CSS que pode te ajudar com isso.

Usando `FlexBox` vc pode definir uma altura auto pro `Container`. Assim ele vai crescer conforme o tamanho da `div` filha que tiver o maior conteúdo. E as divs "irmãs" vão seguir a altura da "irmã" mais alta.

Veja o exemplo para entender melhor.

```css
html, body {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-size: 12px
}
.container {
 max-width: 600px;
 margin: 20px auto;
 display: flex;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
.item {
 margin: 5px;
 padding: 0 10px;
 background: tomato;
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 1.5em;
 flex: 1;
}
h4 {
 text-align: center;
 font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<h4>A altura do .container eh definida pelo tamanho do conteúdo da maior div filha</h4>
<section class="container">
 <div class="item flex">Teste 1</div>
 <div class="item flex">Teste 2 Teste 2</div>
 <div class="item flex">Teste 3 Teste 3 Teste 3</div>
 <div class="item flex">Teste 4 Teste 4 Teste 4 Teste 4 Teste 4</div>
</section>
<section class="container">
 <div class="item flex">Teste 1</div>
 <div class="item flex">Teste 2 Teste 2</div>
 <div class="item flex">Teste 4 Teste 4 Teste 4 Teste 4 Teste 4 Teste 4 Teste 4 Teste 4 Teste 4</div>
 <div class="item flex">Teste 3 Teste 3 Teste 3</div>
</section>
```

Um Guia bem didático sobre FlexBox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: Adicionei a tag display: flex;, e funcionou perfeitamente.

Comment: @AndréBaill que bom que deu certo ai, boa sorte com o projeto. O suporte é do IE 10 para frente como vc pode consultar aqui https://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox

Comment: obrigado Hugo, funcionou certinho.